# iOS block with return value

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, objective-c-blocks

I am using a block from Facebook SDK. It returns a dictionary. I want that dictionary as a return value of a method. I am trying to wrap my head around the whole block concept but need a nudge in the right direction.

The block:
(the argument for the block is a string userFBid)

```
-(NSDictionary*) getMutualFBFriendsWithFBid:(NSString*)fbID {

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/mutualfriends/%@", [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:kFbID],userFBid]
                    parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          result = (NSDictionary*)result;

//return result;                              
       }];
```

}

How do i get the return value?

I have tried to google it, but i cant get my hand around it.

I would appreciate any pointer in the right direction.

**EDIT:**
The main question is the following: I need to the completion handler to call a method in another class... how to do that?

Comment: Requests are made async, so you should process "result" dictionary in that block or create an additional method and call it with the resulting dictionary as an argument.

Comment: I am using the same "result" in different classes, so i would rather be able to call it and use the result in those different classes. Tryin to figure out how.

Comment: @B-Man You could store the `result` in your own public instance variable, and access it within your others classes. Is that what you aim?

Comment: @Bigood yup something like that yes. See edit above. I have to put this method in a Singleton class and use the result in another class. So you are into something, just trying to figure out how to actually do that. I cant imagine, i just assign a public property to the Singleton class and get that whenever i need it, then the block will be called?

Comment: @B-Man I don't get it: why do you want want to call `completionHandler`'s block elsewhere?

Comment: @Bigood i am using this methid in a Singleton class to avoid rewriting it in many other classes. So I have it in one place. So example in two other classes, I need to the the result of this same method, and use the result differently. So when it completes i can update the UI in those other classes. Am i approaching it the wrong way?

Comment: @Bigood that is exactly what i was looking for. I just also edited my question, and you answered it :) Now i will try and implement it, that makes much more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the method `startWithGraphPath` is asynchronous, you can't code as if it was synchronous : it means no return value, because as soon as this method is called, your app will continue to execute to the next line, and won't wait for a returned value.

So, to keep this async, I assume you want to use the result of this in your own function, so call it in your `completionHandler` block:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/mutualfriends/%@", [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:kFbID],userFBid]
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          [self myRockinFunction:result];
       }];

//Considering this function 
-(void)myRockinFunction:(NSDictionary*) fb_result{
    //Do stuff with fb_result
}
```

### Edit

OK, I get it. Modify your method to accept a callback as a parameter :

```
-(NSDictionary*) getMutualFBFriendsWithFBid:(NSString*)fbID andCallback:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))callback {

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/mutualfriends/%@", [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:kFbID],userFBid]
                    parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id result,NSError *error) {
         //You should treat errors first
         //Then cast the result to an NSDictionary
         callback((NSDictionary*) result); //And trigger the callback with the result
    }];
}
```

Then, in your other class, use another block to treat your result :

```
[YourHelperClass getMutualFBFriendsWithFBid:fbID andCallback:^(NSDictionary* result){
    //Use result how you wish
    //Beware, this is async too.
}];
```

Note : you should treat the error before triggering your callback.

### Edit 2 (Help from other users appreciated)

Even better, you might try to pass a callback taking all the parameters (not tested, and not sure of the syntax. If someone can correct me, I'd appreciate):

```
-(NSDictionary*) getMutualFBFriendsWithFBid:(NSString*)fbID andCallback:(void (^)(FBRequestConnection *,NSDictionary *,NSError *))callback {

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/mutualfriends/%@", [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:kFbID],userFBid]
                    parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:callback()]; //Not sure here!
}

[YourHelperClass getMutualFBFriendsWithFBid:fbID andCallback:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,NSDictionary * result,NSError *error){
     //You could deal with errors here now
}];
```

[Here's a reference on Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) for deeper understanding.

Comment: I see... But since the asynchronous request is made in a Singleton class, I need to call the completion method in another class. Is there an easy way to do it, depending on which class is calling the request?

Comment: @B-Man Could you try my second proposition? I'm not sure of it, but it might be better for you

Comment: the first edit is actually working perfectly... the second one is saying it is missing 3 arguments in the callback after "completion handler". im trying to play with it

Comment: @B-Man Try `callback(FBRequestConnection *connection,id result,NSError *error)`

Comment: I tried didn't work. (Just got out of the house will try more later).

Answer (score 1):

You already have it :)

I would write a method to process the dictionary, in order to keep the completionHandler block a little cleaner--but you could write your response-handling code inside the block. As another commenter mentioned, this is async so you're not really "returning" anything...you're handling the completion block when it gets called.

To help you understand a little, the completionHandler block in this case is a chunk of code that you're passing to the method as an argument, for it to call later. In essence, "whenever this call comes back, do this: ^{ ". The implementation of the FBRequest method will call your completionHandler (whatever that may be).

Comment: I understand that part, and I can see how I am approaching this in a wrong way. I am trying to figure a way to call this request from different other classes and how to handle the result when the request is finished.