# How can I change a BOOL local variable's value inside of Objective C block ? I have used "__block" notation, but it doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I change a BOOL local variable's value inside of Objective C block ? I have used "__block" notation, but it doesn't work

```
 - (BOOL)loginUserWithEmail:(NSString *)email andPassword:(NSString *)password {


    __block BOOL result = NO;

    SCPredicate *emailPredicate = [SCPredicate whereKey:@"email" isEqualToString:email];
    SCPredicate *passwordPredicate = [SCPredicate whereKey:@"password" isEqualToString:password];
    SCCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate = [SCCompoundPredicate compoundPredicateWithPredicates:@[emailPredicate, passwordPredicate]];

    [[SHPerson please] giveMeDataObjectsWithPredicate:compoundPredicate parameters:nil completion:^(NSArray *persons, NSError *error) {

        if (persons != nil) {
            result = YES;
        }
    }];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You're doing an asynchronous request by the looks of things – therefore the method will return before the request calls your block. You want to pass a callback block to your `loginUserWithEmail:andPassword:` method. There are a ton of examples of how to do this on SO, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393138/objective-c-callback-handler) & [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883470/ios-block-with-return-value) for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the method is returning the result of NO before your async `giveMeDataObjectsWithPredicate` method has time to complete. Try this instead:

```
- (void)loginUserWithEmail:(NSString *)email andPassword:(NSString *)password withCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL result))completion {    
    SCPredicate *emailPredicate = [SCPredicate whereKey:@"email" isEqualToString:email];
    SCPredicate *passwordPredicate = [SCPredicate whereKey:@"password" isEqualToString:password];
    SCCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate = [SCCompoundPredicate compoundPredicateWithPredicates:@[emailPredicate, passwordPredicate]];

    [[SHPerson please] giveMeDataObjectsWithPredicate:compoundPredicate parameters:nil completion:^(NSArray *persons, NSError *error) {
        if (completion) {
            if (persons != nil) {
                completion(YES);
            } else {
                completion(NO);
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Then you can use this with:

```
[self loginUserWithEmail:email andPassword:password andCompletion:^(BOOL result) {
    // You can now use result here...
}];
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: "Statement requires expression of scalar type ('void' invalid)" when I call that method using block.

Comment: Did you change the return type of the method like I did in the above code? Your old method returns a BOOL but the new one returns void. You're no longer returning the boolean via the method - you're passing it inside of a completion block.